# When I click on the menu button It is not opening the menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
    const menuBtn = document.querySelector('#menuBtn')
    const exitBtn = document.querySelector('#exitBtn');
    const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
    
    menuBtn.addEventListener('click' , () => {
        menu.style.display = 'block'
    })
```

```css
    .fa.fa-bars.menuBtn {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 35px;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .fa.fa-times-circle.exit {
      color: white;
      font-size: 35px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 934px) {
      .max-width {
        padding: 0 50px;
      }
      .fa.fa-bars.menuBtn {
        display: block;
      }
      .navbar .menu {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 110px;
        display: none;
      }
      .menu{
        display: none
           }
      .exit {
        z-index: 999;
        display: none;
        margin: 1.8rem;
      }
      .navbar .menu li {
        display: block;
      }
      .navbar .menu li a {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 20px 0;
        font-size: 35px;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar" id="nav">
                <div class="max-width">
                    <div class="logo"><a id="headSpan" href="index.html">Port<span>folio.</span></a></div>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars menuBtn" id="menuBtn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="exit">    
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle exit" id="exitBtn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </nav>
```

How do I make it work ? I tested to see if the add event listener was working and it was working but when it comes to displaying the menu when clicked it does not work. Any idea what the issue may be ? I am not that good at using Javascript so any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('menu');` doesn't return a single element. It returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). So `menu` isn't an element and `menu.style.display = 'block` doesn't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: can you show how it should be like? may be using foreach or whatever

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to add an `id` to the element, get it and perform the operation on it.

Comment: How do I select the menu then ? If it is not an element , is there a way to do it so that when the button is clicked , the navbar or menu shows @Parco

Comment: Take the first one from the collection? Iterate and add a listener to all of them? Find a different way to get a reference to it? There are many straightforward solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('menu')` gets multiple elements, all of which have the class `'menu'`. The function returns an HTMLCollection, but you can treat it like a list. If you want to use classes, I would recommend using:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')
for (var item of list) {
    // Do Stuff Here
}
```

If you have multiple menus, consider using JQuery with the `.each(function)` method for functions.